# Insert a new row between tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using tableLayout for my app, and I use addView to add new tablerow at the bottom,
but when I want to insert a row maybe between the first and the second row I would have to 
delete all of them and addView all over again, can anyone provide me with a better option?

===============
**row 1**

```
        <---Insert a row here.
```

**row 2**

===============

**row 3**

===============

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new cell at the bottom, and (not deleting, but) re-assigning them.

new row N = New N-1
New row N-1 = New N-2

etc...

After you have finished copying your current rows down, you can create your new row and assign it to the row number you have (essentially) freed.